# iOS - make changes to app without requiring update via app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

This may seem like an odd question, but I'm in the middle of creating an iOS app, and was wondering if there is a way to, in the future, roll out changes to the app without requiring all of the users to download an update.

I've noticed that Snapchat can do this with their filters - new filters are added regularly, without me updating the app.

I've read into 'Cloud code', something Parse had that apparently let you accomplish this. Obviously that's no longer an option.

Also, do Apple even allow this? Seeing as they need to approve every app before letting it onto the App Store, it would seem like they would need to approve any changes first too.

I've thought of strange things like storing a function in a database, then getting the app to download that function and run it - naturally if I were to now change the function in the database, it would change on all users devices instantly. Just how ridiculous is that idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how much flexibility you want.

For example, Spotify does this for UI mainly - backend-driven UI, as they call it. They send a kind of layout from the server and convert it to a real iOS layout, based of a predefined mapping. You can find pretty more details in the Spotify's presentation.

Slides: http://www.slideshare.net/JohnSundell/backenddriven-native-uis

Video (more details): http://www.downvids.net/backend-driven-native-uis-john-sundell-and-diego-cristina-ca--777281.html

So actions can also be divided in similar pieces and abstractions, received from the server and interpreted - sort of scripting is needed. You can't compile and run arbitrary functions on the fly.

Hope it'll give you some ideas you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

See Apple's app store review guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ section 2.4.5 (iv).  Apps are not supposed to download code or resources to add functionality or significantly change the app from what Apple sees during the review process.  And executable memory isn't even writable by sandboxed apps, which makes downloading compiled functions fairly useless.  But downloading Javascript that complies with the above guidelines seems to be allowed.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible though, if I want to roll out updates to a non-app store apps.